# Text Manipulation Excel - How to swap two characters in a string?

Tags: excel, text-manipulation

How would you swap two characters in a string in Excel, with string and position to swap specified by the user?

For example:

User inputs a sentence: "Hi there!"

User inputs an integer between 1 and half of the LEN(sentence): 2

Output: "He theri!"

I am able to replace the first instance, but cannot figure out a way to replace the second.

So far I have used the REPLACE and MID funciton to accomplish what I have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say your initial sentence in `A1` and intereg number in `B1`. Than you could use:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-B1+1,1,MID(A1,B1,1)),B1,1,MID(A1,LEN(A1)-B1+1,1))
```

[image]